# Por que as div "rede-sociais" estão saindo da div quando uso float

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber por que a div redes-sociais saem da `div "menu"` sempre que utilizo o `float` para imagens irem para o lado direito.

**html:**

```
    <header id = "topo">
        <div class = "menu">
            <div class = "nome-empresa">
                <img src = "Dev.png">
            </div>
            <div class = "redes-sociais">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

**css:**

```
 #topo {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: auto;
}

.nome-empresa {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 80%;
}

.redes-sociais {
    float:right;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste link ele pode te ajudar, lá contem inúmeras técnicas de float

Comment: https://www.richardbarros.com.br/css/css-truques-para-dominar-a-propriedade-float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente seu problema esta em definir as propriedades da caixa principal.

```css
    #topo {
        background-color: #000000;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .menu { 
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 1rem;
        align-items: center;
      }

    ul { 
        margin:0;
        }
    ul li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<header id = "topo">
            <div class = "menu">
                <div class = "nome-empresa">
                    <img src = "Dev.png">
                </div>
                <div class = "redes-sociais">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elementos com `float` não respeitam a altura do contêiner onde estão. No seu caso, você tem 2 divs dentro da `div.menu` (contêiner), e como cada div ocupa uma linha inteira e a segunda está com `float`, a altura da `div.menu` será determinada pelo conteúdo da `div.nome-empresa` que não tem `float`. Por isso a segunda div fica saindo da `div.menu`.

Você resolveria isso colocando `overflow: hidden` na `div.menu`, mas ainda sim a `div.redes-sociais` ficaria numa linha abaixo da div anterior, a `.nome-empresa`, veja:

```css
#topo { background-color: #000000; margin: auto; }

.nome-empresa { padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 80%; }

.redes-sociais { float:right; }

ul li { list-style: none; display: inline-block; }

.menu {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header id = "topo">
     <div class = "menu">
         <div class = "nome-empresa">
             <img src = "Dev.png">
         </div>
         <div class = "redes-sociais">
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href = "#"><img src = "link.png" alt= "linkedin" width="30"></a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
 </header>
```